# Problem with De Moivre–Laplace theorem

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Probability that shoe store customer requires shoes of a proper size is $0,15$.     Estimate the compass of customer percent among $2000$ visitors of shoe store, which require a proper size, if the compass is need to be guaranteed with a probability $0,98$.

I use De Moivre–Laplace theorem and based on all problem situation I've had:
$$P_{2000}\left(\alpha, \beta\right) = 0.98= \Phi\left(\frac{\alpha - 300}{\sqrt{255}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{\beta-300}{\sqrt{255}}\right)$$ where $\Phi(x)$ is standard normal distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure what "compass" means in this context. A familiar situation would be that you want to choose an interval like you wrote in your equation but with $\alpha>300,\alpha-300=-(\beta-300)$ (i.e. a symmetric interval around the mean). In this case you would solve for $\alpha$ by setting $\Phi((\beta-300)/\sqrt{255})=0.01$.

Comment: @Ian Sorry, I don't understand... Why is it need to be symmetric? And can you please explain me why $\Phi((\beta-300)/\sqrt{255})$ eq 0.01? Thank you!

Comment: It does not always need to be symmetric, I just have no idea what your question is asking because I don't know what a "compass" means in this context. Anyway, in general when $x>0,\Phi(x)-\Phi(-x)=1-\alpha$ is equivalent to $\Phi(-x)=\alpha/2$. This follows from the symmetry of the normal distribution.

Comment: @If the original question is in german, please post the original text as a comment because there are some mistakes in the translation and one cannot help you. Thanks